# Excel: How to add warning message if Macro used twice

Tags: excel, vba

I got some help from another member with my question [Copy Range and Paste Values in another Sheet's specific Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21648122/excel-vba-copy-range-and-paste-values-in-another-sheets-specific-range#21648151) and so far everything is working great thanks to @simoco but now I'm just thinking I want to add an additional feature to it.

How can I add a message box with the option to "Ok" to run the macro or "Cancel" to not run it?

Since I know it will be most likely be used with duplicate data and I don't know how to stop it from pasting the same data over again, I want to at least warn to double check before running the macro or to run it if sure.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Sub test()
    If MsgBox("Run macro?", vbOKCancel + vbQuestion, "My Title") = vbCancel Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'your code here
End Sub
```

if user press "Cancel" button, the macro would be terminated.

Comment: Awesome. this will do and it works great. so simple to implement it. thank you again. =)