# Delete duplicates based on multiple columns and sum one of the columns

Tags: vba, excel

**I found a way to my problem, I just added an extra column to combine data in multiple cells.**

**Like =B1&C1&E1 filled this down to lastrow in column G and searched for duplicates in this row.**

**I know I asked this Question in 2016 but better late than never i guess.**

I use this script, but this only checks for one column if the row is duplicate or not.

How do i modify this to check for multiple columns (two is fine).

```
Sub merge_duplicates()
Dim count, count_1, found_str
count = 2
Do Until Range("A" & count) = ""
found_str = 0
For count_1 = 1 To count - 1
If InStr(1, Range("E" & count), Range("E" & count_1)) > 0 Then
Range("D" & count_1) = Range("D" & count_1) + Range("D" & count)
found_str = 1
End If
Next
If found_str = 1 Then
Rows(count).Delete
Else
count = count + 1
End If
Loop
End Sub
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M01hO.jpg)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This way is so much faster, first look for the last row in range, then remove duplicates at it. (Faster than looping around)

```
Sub test()

    Dim lastrow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            lastrow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            lastrow = 1
        End If

        'Array(1, 2, 16) means 1 - for A, 2 for B and 16 for P columns
        .Range("A1:P" & lastrow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 16), _
            Header:=xlYes
    End With
End Sub
```

Answered here:
[excel: check for duplicate rows based on 3 columns and keep one row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21660648/excel-check-for-duplicate-rows-based-on-3-columns-and-keep-one-row)

Comment: Works good for deleting the duplicates but this doesn't sum up column "D"

Comment: Just change the Columns in the .RemoveDuplicates, to take from A to D change the Columns:Array(1,2,16) to Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4)

Comment: Ups, now I got it, It's easy to loop through and do by hand, just try it yourself, later I come here and help again if you could'nt find some way out

Comment: Doing it by hand is not a good option because i have to work with 70k+ data. That would take quite some time.