# Copy filtered range, paste skip blanks

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to filter a sheet, and copy the results to another sheet. Some columns contain formulas that I don't want to copy over, as the destination sheet is blank aside from those columns (filled with different formulas). I'm clearing the contents of these cells with a separate macro. Disclaimer; my knowledge of Excel VBA comes from recording macros, stackoverflow, and a girlfriend who codes, so this might look pretty rough.

When I copy an unfiltered range and paste it as values, skipping blanks, it works perfectly. Once I filter the range and repeat the same steps, it doesn't "skip blanks", and overwrites the formulas. **Do I just need to create a helper sheet to paste the filtered range to, re-copy as a contiguous range, and then paste skipping blanks?**

Below is my code, thanks in advance for the help.

```
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row


Sheets("Selection & Execution").Activate
Set Sheet = ActiveSheet
Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Find("Selected?", , xlValues, xlWhole)
    With Sheet
            .Unprotect 
            .Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
            .Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            .Range("A4:EA20000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).ClearContents
            .Range("3:3").AutoFilter Field:=rng1.Column, Criteria1:= _
                "<>", Operator:=xlAnd
            .Range("A4", "EA" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

    End With

wb1.Activate
Sheets("Selection & Execution").Activate
Set rng2 = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Find("Employee Number", , xlValues, xlWhole)

If rng2.Offset(1, 0) = "" Then
rng2.Offset(1, -5).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
     :=True, Transpose:=False
wb2.Close SaveChanges:=False

Else
rng2.End(xlDown).Offset(1, -5).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=True, Transpose:=False
wb2.Close SaveChanges:=False
End If
```

Comment: you can delete the blank cells after copy paste http://stackoverflow.com/a/40045460/1383168

Comment: that doesn't preserve my formulas that i'm trying to paste the data around..

Comment: sorry, I didn't read the question fully. You can loop over the visible cells and copy them based on their `.Row` property.