# In main sheet there is 800 names(A1:A800). Each cell should go to different sheet with an order. First cell to first sheet etc

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste, cells

I have nearly 800 cells(A1:A800) in my main sheet. Each cell should copy to different sheet with an order. First cell in main sheet('main'!A1) copy to first sheet('1'!A1) , second cell('main'!A2) copy to second sheet('2'!A1) etc.I created 800 sheets already. I don't know VBA very well. I couldn't find any code that fits my problem. Thanks for help!

[image: screenshot showing many values in column A]

Comment: 1. Have you tried anything at all? 2. What does "go to different sheet" mean - where on the sheet is this cell being copied to (presumably)? 3. [Why is "Can someone help me" not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: You don’t want to create sheets, but each cell from the main sheet needs to be on a different sheet - how?

Comment: This question makes no sense. Please review your wording, keeping in mind that your readers don't already *know* what you're trying to achieve. "Each cell should go to different sheet" is directly contradicting "we don't need to create sheets". Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: 1) Yes i tried many codes. I could't solve it. 2)I created 800 sheet already. First cell in main sheet ('main'!A1) copy to first sheet('1'!A1).  I added pic to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am seeing what you are trying to do, it shouldn't be too hard.
You could hardcode a for loop to 800.

```
for i = 2 to 800
    Range("A"&i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(i).Range("A" & i)
next
```

[This is similar albeit a bit more involved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21648122/copy-range-and-paste-values-in-another-sheets-specific-range)